# mvc4 get date values from form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Am creating a checkout system. Part of the form requires the expiry date of the card being used. This consists of 2 small text boxes, 1 for the month, 1 for the year. Am using the code below in my view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(c => c.expiryDate)
@Html.HiddenFor(c => c.expiryDate.Day)
@Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.expiryDate.Month, new { @class = "ccDate" })
<span class="ccDateSep">/</span>
@Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.expiryDate.Year, new { @class = "ccDate" })
```

However when the form is submitted the date keeps coming out as 01/01/0001. All other fields come through fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need a single input field if you want automatic binding to a DateTime property.

Comment: @Stijn - problem with that is that you will hit a lot of different culture problems and will fail at some point on binding it. Having it separate is a good workaround but there are also ways to make it work with your proposed solution but very complicated. how are you parsing it to DateTime? I see no field on the form showing/binding the date. what is your code behind like?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas You're absolutely correct. When using a single field, you're almost required to use a datepicker control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Ufuk's answer, when doing this in the past, I have created properties for the day, month and year that I bind the dropdowns to on the client.  Then in the controller, I will assemble the values into a valid date and populate the property.  for example, my model might look like this for a class containing a DateOfBirth.

```
snip
public DateTime dob {get;set;}
public string dobDay {get;set;}
public string dobMonth {get;set;
public string dobYear {get;set;}
snip
```

I would bind the dropdowns to the dobDay, dobMonth and dobYear fields, then in your controller reassemble them into a DateTime like so:

```
DateTime temp = new DateTime(dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear);
model.dob = temp;
```

I'm not sure the arguments are in the right order in the DateTime constructor, but that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime` struct is immutable. You can't just create an instance and change its `Day`, `Month` or `Year`.You should directly bind the `expiryDate` property or you will have to create new properties in your model for month and year values. Then you can create an instance yourself using the constructor.